# Android java : delete selected file / folder

Tags: java, android, delete-file

How to delete the selected file / folder by using long pressed ?
I'm developing an File Explorer app and there are listed folder and file from my storage.
I want to have a delete function for the `longpressed()`.

```
public void longpressed(){

this.getListView().setLongClickable(true);
this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewNoteActivity.this , AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK)
        .setTitle("Delete Folder / File")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete the selected folder / file ?")
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which ) { 
                 boolean success = true;


                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have successfully delete." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();



            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have Failed to delete." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
            }

         })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                // do nothing
            }
         })
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
         .show();
        return true;
    }
});

}
```

item select coding:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    FileInfo fileDescriptor = fileArrayListAdapter.getItem(position);
    if (fileDescriptor.isFolder() || fileDescriptor.isParent()) {
        currentFolder = new File(fileDescriptor.getPath());
        fill(currentFolder);
    } else {

        fileSelected = new File(fileDescriptor.getPath());
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_FILE_SELECTED,
                fileSelected.getAbsolutePath());
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        Log.i("FILE CHOOSER", "result ok");
              }
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [File class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) API reference.

To delete a file:

```
new File(path).delete()
```

To delete a folder:

```
private void deleteFolderRecursive(File dir) {
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                deleteFolderRecursive(file);
            } else {
                file.delete();
            }
        }
    }

    dir.delete();
}
```

Comment: can you explain to more detail ?

Comment: what information are you missing? I provided a method for deleting a file, and another for deleting a folder, isn't what you asked?

Comment: i have posted my item select coding. Actually what I want is in my file explorer I long pressed the item that I select it pop up a message to ask for delete. But the thing is I have no idea how to do delete file and folder function. So I asking for help. hope you understand what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
 File dir =new File(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/YourFOlderName");
            boolean success = deleteDir(dir);
```

Where:

`getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/YourFOlderName"`

is the path to the folder.

And:

```
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    }
```

The above will delete all the children inside the directory.

if your folder is on the External SD Card the path should be mounted like:

Never hardcode the sdcard, you must use

`Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)`

will let you know if the memory is loaded. Then use:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: The above is not hard coded and assumes that you are saving the folder in your app directory.

Comment: I have try out just now it doesn't work with my code. I have posted my item select coding. Any idea to do that deletion ?

Comment: What is the path to your folder? put this `File dir =new File(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/YourFOlderName");
            boolean success = deleteDir(dir);` where you want to delete. Replace the path with your path.

Comment: undefined getActivity() and if I enter my folder name in  "/YourFOlderName" mean that is not the folder I selected from the file explorer.

Comment: use YourClassName.this instead of getActivity(). You have to dynamically add the folder name on click of the list view. Put a variable there.

Comment: okay so far i tested `File dir =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/CalendarNote/");` all folder inside CalendarNote are actually deleted. But how do I put the selected file name/ folder name to `"CalendarNote/" + ?"` it so difficult

Comment: use a String: 
`String folderName;
foldername = "/CalendarNote";` and then :`File dir =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +folderName);`

Comment: i think you misunderstand my comment. sorry for my broken english. `"CalendarNote/" + ?"` the ? which mean the file or folder that I selected. see my item select code on the top. So far i have try out `"CalendarNote/" + currentFolder"` or `"CalendarNote/" + fileSelected"` it doesn't work.